# How to retrieve trips from historical data?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following table `mytable` in Hive:

```
id    radar_id     car_id     datetime
1     A21          123        2017-03-08 17:31:19.0
2     A21          555        2017-03-08 17:32:00.0
3     A21          777        2017-03-08 17:33:00.0
4     B15          123        2017-03-08 17:35:22.0
5     B15          555        2017-03-08 17:34:05.0
5     B15          777        2017-03-08 20:50:12.0
6     A21          123        2017-03-09 11:00:00.0
7     C11          123        2017-03-09 11:10:00.0
8     A21          123        2017-03-09 11:12:00.0
9     A21          555        2017-03-09 11:12:10.0
10    B15          123        2017-03-09 11:14:00.0
11    C11          555        2017-03-09 11:20:00.0
```

I want to get the routes of cars passing through radars `A21` and `B15` within the same trip. For example, if the date is different for the same `car_id`, then it is not the same trip. Basically, I want to consider that the maximum time difference between radars `A21` and `B15` for the same vehicle should be 30 minutes. If it's bigger, then the trip is not the same, like for example for the `car_id` `777`.

My final goal is to count the average number of trips per day (non-unique, so if the same car passed 2 times by the same route, then it should be calculated 2 times).

The expected result is the following one:

```
radar_start   radar_end       avg_tripscount_per_day
A21           B15             1.5
```

On the date `2017-03-08` there are 2 trips between radars `A21` and `B15` (car `777` is not considered due to 30 minutes limit), while on the date `2017-03-09` there is only 1 trip. The average is 2+1=1.5 trips per day.

How can I get this result? Basically, I do not know how to introduce 30 minutes limit in the query and how to group rides by `radar_start` and `radar_end`.

Thanks.

**Update:**

1. The trip is registered at the date it started.
2. If the car was triggered by radar `A21` at `2017-03-08 23:55` and by radar `B15` at `2017-03-09 00:15`, then it should be considered as the same trip registered for the date `2017-03-08`.
3. In case of `ids` 6 and 8 the same car `123` passed by `A21` two times, and then it turned to `B15` (`id` 10). The last ride with `id` 8 should be considered. So, `8-10`. Thus, the closest previous to `B15`. The interpretation is that a car passed by `A21` two times and the second time is turned to `B15`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I am using Hive.

Comment: @Strawberry: Which case do you refer to? The maximum difference in minutes should be 30 minutes, not more. If more than 30 minutes passed between radar `A21` and `B15` (or vice versa), then it is not the same trip and it should not be counted. It should be then ignored.

Comment: @Strawberry: So, it's the same trip then, because the difference is lower than 30 minutes.

Comment: Even though they're on different days?

Comment: @Strawberry: No, if these are different days, then these are different trips. In this case I consider the difference in minutes as 20 minutes plus 24 hours, so it's more than 30 minutes.

Comment: It's not plus 24 hours. It's just 20 minutes - 5 minutes before, and 15 minutes after midnight. (Sorry, I made a typo. I meant 23.55 and 00:15!!)

Comment: @Strawberry: I guess I misunderstood your question. Sorry! I read it again and yes, if you mean the case when the first radar is triggered in the night at 23:55 and the second radar at 00:15, then it's the same trip, though the date was switched in the midnight.

Comment: Something wrong with sample data? How about Id 6 and Id 8 `A21`, car `123` the same day, and time difference 12 minutes. And how about `ids`, shouldn't it be unique?

Comment: I think you need to revise your question accordingly. Also, does the trip register on the day it started or the day it ended, or both?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: yes, but this is not the difference between radars `A21` and `B15`. It's the difference for the same radar `A21`. I am only interested in trips between `A21` and `B15`. Imagine that it's possible to enter `A21` from different directions.

Comment: @Strawberry: That's the good point. Thanks. It is registered at the day it started.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: `ids` are not unique in historical data. Imagine that the same car is circulating through the same radar several times while searching for a parking place.

Comment: So how to know which is one the same trip? With id 6 or 8? With id 6 car 123 started trip at 11:00:00 and the same car with id 8 started trip 11:12:00, and I see radar B15 car 123 were at 11:14:00, so how about it?

Comment: A final thought. Is hive the right tool for this? How large is the dataset (megabytes or terabytes?)

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas: Ok, good question. The last registration should be considered. So, the closest previous to `B15`. The interpretation is that a car passed by `A21` two times and the second time is turned to `B15`.

Comment: @Strawberry: I do not have another choice. The data is stored in Hive (3 Gb) and I do not have a control over Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  count(*) / count(distinct to_date(datetime))    as trips_per_day

from   (select  radar_id
               ,datetime
               ,lead(radar_id) over w  as next_radar_id
               ,lead(datetime) over w  as next_datetime                    

        from    mytable

        where   radar_id in ('A21','B15')

        window  w as 
                (
                    partition by  car_id
                    order by      datetime
                )
        ) t

where   radar_id        = 'A21'
    and next_radar_id   = 'B15'
    and datetime + interval '30' minutes >= next_datetime
;
```

---

```
+----------------+
| trips_per_day  |
+----------------+
| 1.5            |
+----------------+
```

P.s.
If your version does not support intervals, the last code record could be replaced by -
`and to_unix_timestamp(datetime) + 30*60 > to_unix_timestamp(next_datetime)`

Comment: Thanks. I get this error `FAILED: ParseException line 21:18 cannot recognize input near 'interval' ''30'' 'minutes' in expression specification''`

Comment: In my case `datetime` is string. I guess that this is the issue. How can I cast it to datetime?

Comment: (1) This is a tested code (2) Intervals were introduced on Hive 1.2.0, 18 May 2015, more than 2 years ago. (3)  If you are using STRING instead of TIMESTAMP (why?) than use CAST (4) you can always convert the timestamp to unixtime

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a control over Db. I agree that it's strange to have `datetime` as string. So, do I understand correctly that everywhere `datetime` appears I should substitute it by `cast(datetime as date)`? But in this case I will drop time part.

Comment: cast(datetime as timestamp)

Comment: Hmm, I get the error `ParseException line 1:407 cannot recognize input near 'interval' ''30'' 'minutes' in expression`: Query: `select count(*) / count(distinct to_date(datetime)) as trips_per_day from (select radar_id,cast(datetime as timestamp),lead(radar_id) over w as next_radar_id,lead(cast(datetime as timestamp)) over w as next_datetime from mytable where radar_id in ('A21','B15') window w as (partition by car_id order by cast(datetime as timestamp))) t where radar_id = 'A21' and next_camera_id = 'B15' and cast(datetime as timestamp) + interval '30' minutes >= next_datetime;`

Comment: What is your Hive version?

Comment: /etc/hive/2.5.3.0-37. So, it's Hive 2.5

Comment: No. `select version()`

Comment: Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37. By the way `select version();` does not work for me from hive. I did `hive --version`.

Comment: `version()` was introduced on Hive 2.1.0

Comment: So, I dispose of some old version of Hive on the cluster. However, as you said intervals were introduced in 1.2. It means that my version should support your code. Strange.

Comment: Is it possible to substitute intervals?

Comment: Yes, I already referred to this. cast the timestamp to unixtime and add seconds instead of an interval

Comment: `select count(*) / count(distinct to_date(datetime)) as trips_per_day from (select radar_id,unix_timestamp(cast(datetime as timestamp)),lead(radar_id) over w as next_radar_id,lead(unix_timestamp(cast(datetime as timestamp))) over w as next_datetime from mytable where radar_id in ('A21','B15') window w as (partition by car_id order by unix_timestamp(cast(datetime as timestamp)))) t where radar_id = 'A21' and next_camera_id = 'B15' and unix_timestamp(cast(datetime as timestamp)) + 1800 seconds >= next_datetime;`.

Comment: I get `ParseException line 1:476 missing EOF at 'seconds' near '1800'` for the above query.

Comment: ?! `to_unix_timestamp(datetime) + 30*60 > to_unix_timestamp(next_datetime)`

Comment: Thank you. I still have a small issue with table alias or column reference, getting _c1 instead of `datetime`, but I will ask another question for this particular issue.

Comment: I posted the relevant question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486630/semanticexception-error-10004-line-1118-invalid-table-alias-or-column-refere), in case you may have time to check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I missed that you're using `Hive` so started writing query for `SQL-Server`, but maybe it will help for you. Try something like this:

**QUERY**

```
select radar_start, 
       radar_end, 
       convert(decimal(6,3), count(*)) / convert(decimal(6,3), count(distinct dt)) as avg_tripscount_per_day
from (
    select 
        t1.radar_id as radar_start,
        t2.radar_id as radar_end,
        convert(date, t1.[datetime]) dt,
        row_number() over (partition by t1.radar_id, t1.car_id, convert(date, t1.[datetime]) order by t1.[datetime] desc) rn1,
        row_number() over (partition by t2.radar_id, t2.car_id, convert(date, t2.[datetime]) order by t2.[datetime] desc) rn2
    from trips as t1
    join trips as t2 on t1.car_id = t2.car_id 
        and datediff(minute,t1.[datetime], t2.[datetime]) between 0 and 30
        and t1.radar_id = 'A21' 
        and t2.radar_id = 'B15'
)x
where rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1
group by radar_start, radar_end
```

**OUPUT**

```
radar_start radar_end   avg_tripscount_per_day
A21         B15         1.5000000000
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table trips
(
    id int,
    radar_id char(3),
    car_id int,
    [datetime] datetime
)
insert into trips values
(1,'A21',123,'2017-03-08 17:31:19.0'),
(2,'A21',555,'2017-03-08 17:32:00.0'),
(3,'A21',777,'2017-03-08 17:33:00.0'),
(4,'B15',123,'2017-03-08 17:35:22.0'),
(5,'B15',555,'2017-03-08 17:34:05.0'),
(5,'B15',777,'2017-03-08 20:50:12.0'),

(6,'A21',123,'2017-03-09 11:00:00.0'),
(7,'C11',123,'2017-03-09 11:10:00.0'),
(8,'A21',123,'2017-03-09 11:12:00.0'),

(9,'A21',555,'2017-03-09 11:12:10.0'),
(8,'B15',123,'2017-03-09 11:14:00.0'),
(9,'C11',555,'2017-03-09 11:20:00.0')
```

Comment: Thanks! I am testing your query. One question: in my case `datetime` is a string. Unfortunately, I do not have a control over DB. I have only read rights. Should I use `to_date(datetime)`?

Comment: You count each car only once per day.

Comment: @Dinosaurius yes,  looks like `to_date(datetime)` is built-in function in Hive.