# SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 11:18 Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This question is related to the answer of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481288/how-to-retrieve-trips-from-historical-data/45483836?noredirect=1#comment77933116_45483836). Please notice that `datetime` is string. Therefore I convert it to unix timestamp.

I execute this query in Hive 1.2.1:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct to_date(datetime)) as trips_per_day 

from (select radar_id,to_unix_timestamp(datetime),lead(radar_id) over w as 
      next_radar_id,lead(to_unix_timestamp(datetime)) over w as 
      next_datetime 
      from mytable 
      where radar_id in ('A21','B15') window w as 
     (partition by car_id order by to_unix_timestamp(datetime))) t 

where radar_id = 'A21' and next_radar_id = 'B15' 
      and to_unix_timestamp(datetime) + 30*60 > to_unix_timestamp(next_datetime);
```

But I get the following error:

> SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 11:18 Invalid table alias or
>   column reference 'datetime': (possible column names are: radar_id, _c1,
>   next_radar_id, next_datetime)

Where is an error?

Comment: You have not aliased `to_unix_timestamp(datetime)` and in any case no need to do this conversion at this point. Check my answer for your previous question for the `P.s.` part

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Ok, my last line in this question looks the same. This is what I try to run, but get the error regarding alias. What should I change in this query in order to alias `to_unix_timestamp(datetime)`? I think my current query (the one that I posted here) is the duplicate of your answer, but it does not work for me for some small detail that escapes from me.

Comment: No, get back to the previous question and run my query replacing the last line of my code with the line I gave in the `P.s.`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: According to P.S. the last code record `and datetime + interval '30' minutes >= next_datetime` should be replaced by `and to_unix_timestamp(datetime) + 30*60 > to_unix_timestamp(next_datetime)`, right? Isn't it what I have here in my question?

Comment: Yes, but you have changed other parts of the query. `from (select radar_id,to_unix_timestamp(datetime),lead...`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: It works now!!! Thank you so much.