# How to check the traffic between several pairs of radars?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following working query in Hive (see the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481288/how-to-retrieve-trips-from-historical-data)). It returns the average number of  rides through the route segment between radars `A21` and `B15`.

```
select  count(*) / count(distinct to_date(datetime))    as trips_per_day

from   (select  radar_id
               ,datetime
               ,lead(radar_id) over w  as next_radar_id
               ,lead(datetime) over w  as next_datetime                    

        from    mytable

        where   radar_id in ('A21','B15')

        window  w as 
                (
                    partition by  car_id
                    order by      datetime
                )
        ) t

where   radar_id        = 'A21'
    and next_radar_id   = 'B15'
    and to_unix_timestamp(datetime) + 30*60 > to_unix_timestamp(next_datetime)
;
```

I want to extend this query so that it checks routes `A21->B15`, `B15->A22`, `D12->E23`. Instead of a single number, the query should output the table like this:

```
radar_start    radar_end   avg_trips_per_day
A21            B15         1.5
B15            A22         ...
...
```

How can I pass the pairs of radars?